# How to provide multiple line help message with Clap?

Tags: rust, clap

Is there a way for us to have line breaks in clap's help message?

I tried multiple line comments, also tried inserting `\n` in the mix. But neither works.

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about)]
struct Args {
    /// The input filename.\n
    /// Hello world!
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
    input: String,
}
```

Output:

```
USAGE:
    ascii_tree --input <INPUT>

OPTIONS:
    -h, --help             Print help information
    -i, --input <INPUT>    The input filename.\n Hello world!
    -V, --version          Print version information
```

Is there away to achieve the following?

```
USAGE:
    ascii_tree --input <INPUT>

OPTIONS:
    -h, --help             Print help information
    -i, --input <INPUT>    The input filename.
                           Hello world!
    -V, --version          Print version information
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know of two options. Make the second line only contain `///`, or use `verbatim_doc_comment`:

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Args {
    /// Name of the person to greet
    ///
    /// Has a multi-line help.
    #[clap(short, long)]
    name: String,

    /// Number of times to greet
    /// Use the verbatim arg
    #[clap(short, long, verbatim_doc_comment)]
    count: u8,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=95f4bb4dedaae8022f78ba1c725d2d8d)

Comment: Is there a way to set `verbatim_doc_comment` to all args at once?

Comment: Seeing how [few occurrences it has in the code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aclap-rs/clap%20VerbatimDocComment&type=code), I highly doubt it. Though this could also be done by an external crate or a proc macro you write yourself. (There is [a crate](https://lib.rs/crates/script-macro) that allows you to define short proc macros inline in a scripting language. That might be the right choice here.)

Answer (score 5):

You can add the `verbatim_doc_comment` option:

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about)]
struct Args {
    /// The input filename.
    /// Hello world!
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser, verbatim_doc_comment)]
    input: String,
}
```

```
USAGE:
    ascii_tree --input <INPUT>

OPTIONS:
    -h, --help             Print help information
    -i, --input <INPUT>    The input filename.
                           Hello world!
    -V, --version          Print version information
```

It seems without it, Rust only recognizes paragraph breaks via double-newline.